Mongo Trigger - Match Expression for all items in an array
I have a mongo trigger sending events to AWS Eventbridge on insert/update to a certain table.
I need to exclude 2 fields from setting off the trigger, as it results in an endless loop when my worker adds the item to a 3rd party system and then updates the table with the ID for the new system, endlessly triggering updates to the table.
The rule i have below works for 1 item, except i cannot figure out how to dynamically look at all "item levels" inside the "SubCategories" array. This only ignores updates to the 0th item in the list, and i have some with upwards for 300 categories so i cant just hardcode 0,1,2,3 over and over. Every attempt i have tried fails to work, or throws and error for invalid expression.
{
  "$and": [
    {
      "updateDescription.updatedFields.SubCategories.1.jumpsellerSubCategoryId": {
        "$exists": false
      }
    },
    {
      "updateDescription.updatedFields.jumpsellerCategoryId": {
        "$exists": false
      }
    }
  ]
}

I tried replacing the array depth of 0,1,2, etc with $ and that seems to be a valid expression in mongo but the filter does not work at all.
Solution after much digging:
{
    "$expr": {
        "$and": [
            {
                "$not": {
                    "$anyElementTrue": {
                        "$map": {
                            "input": {
                                "$cond": {
                                    "if": {
                                        "$isArray": {
                                            "$objectToArray": "$updateDescription.updatedFields"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "then": {
                                        "$objectToArray": "$updateDescription.updatedFields"
                                    },
                                    "else": []
                                }
                            },
                            "as": "field",
                            "in": {
                                "$and": [
                                    {
                                        "$regexMatch": {
                                            "input": "$$field.k",
                                            "regex": "^SubCategories\\.\\d+\\.jumpsellerSubCategoryId$"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "$eq": [
                                            {
                                                "$type": "$$field.v"
                                            },
                                            "int"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "$not": {
                    "$anyElementTrue": {
                        "$map": {
                            "input": {
                                "$cond": {
                                    "if": {
                                        "$isArray": {
                                            "$objectToArray": "$updateDescription.updatedFields"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "then": {
                                        "$objectToArray": "$updateDescription.updatedFields"
                                    },
                                    "else": []
                                }
                            },
                            "as": "field",
                            "in": {
                                "$and": [
                                    {
                                        "$eq": [
                                            "$$field.k",
                                            "jumpsellerCategoryId"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "$eq": [
                                            {
                                                "$type": "$$field.v"
                                            },
                                            "int"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}


remove 1: SubCategories.jumpsellerSubCategoryId will check all subdocuments in the array

That does not work either, these are still slipping through:
"operationType":"update","clusterTime":{"T":1722529433,"I":11},..."ns":{"db":"evexia","coll":"health-categories"},"documentKey":{"_id":"66aa7ccf21cb0bc35475c016"},"updateDescription":{"updatedFields":{"SubCategories.0.jumpsellerSubCategoryId":1977417},"removedFields":[],"truncatedArrays":[]}}}'

right, totally forgot the key is a string that represents the path, not a real path.  I agree $objectToArray and $regex* are unavoidable. Please see my answer for an alternative query.

I would simplify it a bit by combining $filter and $size of the filtered array:
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$eq": [
          {
            "$size": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": {
                  "$objectToArray": "$updateDescription.updatedFields"
                },
                "as": "aField",
                "cond": {
                  "$regexMatch": {
                    "input": "$$aField.k",
                    "regex": "\\.jumpsellerCategoryId$"
                  }
                },
                "limit": 1
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]

The regexp condition matches jumpsellerCategoryId at any depth, which should cover both $and conditions. The limit is an optimization to stop after the first match, as $eq checks for 0 size - anything longer than that is a no-match, so the first match will suffice.
